# Is Java7 intelligent in collecting objects if they are not used further in a scope, although the scope has not completely ended

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, jvm, scope

Consider the following code:

```
public class BitSetTest
{
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Start?");
        int ch = System.in.read();

        List<Integer> numbers = getSortedNumbers();

        System.out.println("Generated numbers");
        ch = System.in.read();

        RangeSet<Integer> rangeSet = TreeRangeSet.create();
        for (Integer number : numbers)
        {
            rangeSet.add(Range.closed(number, number));
        }

        System.out.println("Finished rangeset");
        ch = System.in.read();

        BitSet bitset = new BitSet();
        for (Integer number : numbers)
        {
            bitset.set(number.intValue());
        }

        System.out.println("Finished bitset");
        ch = System.in.read();

        //System.out.println(numbers.size());
        //System.out.println(rangeSet.isEmpty());
        //System.out.println(bitset.size());
    }

    private static List<Integer> getSortedNumbers()
    {
        int max = 200000000;
        int n = max / 10;
        List<Integer> numbers = Lists.newArrayListWithExpectedSize(max);
        File file = new File("numbers.txt");
        if (file.exists())
        {
            try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)))
            {
                String line = reader.readLine();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    numbers.add(Integer.valueOf(line));
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e1)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException(e1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                int number = (int) (Math.random() * max);
                numbers.add(number);

                if (i > 0 && i % 10000 == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            }
            Collections.sort(numbers);
            try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file)))
            {
                writer.write(numbers.get(0) + "");
                for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
                {
                    writer.write("\n");
                    writer.write(numbers.get(i) + "");
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e1)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException(e1);
            }
        }

        return numbers;
    }
}
```

At the first pause(System.in.read()), JConsole shows memory usage as 4MB.
At the second pause("Generated Numbers"), since a large list is instantiated, the memory usage jumps to 922MB.
At the next pause ("Finished rangeset"), after running GC the memory comes back to 4MB which means the list is collected although the function has not ended in scope.

When the commented sys outs are uncommented and used, then the list does not get collected till the sysout gets executed.

Just wanted to understand whether the JVM is intelligent enough to determine the scope of an object based on the point from where it is not being used any further?

Comment: You basically prove it yourself already; very interesting test and very interesting results. It is not so hard to accept that the JVM is capable of doing this kind of optimization; it might even happen at compile time. If you're interested you might examine the byte code (disassembled) that is generated upon compilation to see if it drastically changes.

Comment: I would guess that this isn't only up to the GC but to the JIT compiler as well. The CLR, for example, has this kind of optimization. It's very likely that it's also present in JVM implementations.

Comment: Perfectly as expected considering how tracing GCs and HotSpot's oopmaps work. Just writing this comment here so that I (hopefully) don't forget to write an answer some time.. :-) The short answer is - as you've pretty much proven already - yes.

Comment: @all - Thank you for providing your comments on the same. Interesting to know that this happens at compile time itself.

Answer (score 1):

Garbage collection is [based on generations](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html) (there are some [changes](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-8-permgen-metaspace) in Java 8). Until Java 8 memory used to be divided into 3 parts: Young generation, Old generation and PermGen. All newly created objects will get into young generation, and if they are still available after some time they will be migrated to Old generation. PermGen used to be used mostly for JVM's own data. Garbage collection of young generation is called minor garbage collection and happens relatively frequently.

Java approach to garbage collection is "Mark and Swipe" (see the first link) and it marks all objects which are not referenced by any life code as dead and clean them up (swipe).

In your particular case the following is happening:

1. Java loads your class into young memory generation;
2. Java kicks off main class;
3. Your code allocates more memory in young generation;
4. While your code runs all these memory is referenced by life code therefore if not cleaned;
5. Your program stops running;
6. Garbage collection kicks in and detects that all data, and the class itself is not referenced any longer by any life code, therefore it marks it for deletion and eventually cleanup.

Based on what you are saying there is a good chance that your class and all your data doesn't even make to Old generation.

To be more clear: garbage collection is happening in parallel with your code and therefore can detect that some data is not referenced any more. Assuming that it detects if object is no longer referenced based on method end is not always correct (and proven by your test).